# attempting to plot the asymptotic expansion of the complementary error function

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

I was trying to plot the asymptotic expansion of erfc(x) for some value of x:

```
exact[x_] := 1/Sqrt[\[Pi]]*Gamma[1/2, x^2];
seriesz[x_, n_] := 
Exp[-x^2]/(x*Sqrt[\[Pi]])
Sum[(-1)^m* (2 m - 1)!! /(2^m *x^(2 m)), {m, 1, n}];

x = 2;
mmax = 5*x;

Print[StringForm["Exact answer: ``", exact[1.0*x]]]
Show[Plot[{exact[x]}, {m, 0, mmax}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}], ListPlot[Table[{m, seriesz[x, m]}, {m, 0, mmax}]]]
```

but the series is always ends up much lower on the plot than the actual value. Instead of getting something where the series oscillates around the exact value, what I'm getting when I run this code is:

```
Exact answer: 0.0046777349810472645`
```

[image]

When what I'm looking for is this (which I get when I make this alteration to the code):

```
seriesz[x_, n_] := 0.00517 + Exp[-x^2]/(x*Sqrt[\[Pi]])*Sum[(-1)^m* (2 m - 1)!! /(2^m *x^(2 m)), {m, 1, n}];
```

[image]

Any advice what I'm doing wrong that the series isn't centered around the exact value and instead is centered around some smaller value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be an error in your expression?  *Mathematica* can do asymptotic expansions using `Series`, I believe. Consider this:

```
f[x_] = 1/Sqrt[π]*Gamma[1/2, x^2];
ListPlot[
  Table[Normal@Series[f[x], {x, ∞, n}] /. x -> 2, {n, 1, 20, 2}]
  , PlotRange -> All
  , Epilog -> {Line[{{0, f[2]}, {25, f[2]}}]}
 ]
```

results in the following:

[image]

Comment: I did not realise Mathematica had that capability!  And I see in your code that to change x, you changed f(2). Useful, thank you!

Comment: Could you just explain what the purpose of {n, 1, 20, 2} in the above code segment is?

Comment: The table index n (which is the order of the expansion, essentially), goes from 1 to 20 in steps of 2. I did this because the expansion had only odd parts of x.